# Error while creating a procedure mysql CRUD

Tags: mysql, crud, procedure

I keep getting a syntax error at line 9

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ItemsAddOrEdit`(
_itm_id INT,
_itm_name VARCHAR(255),
_itm_price FLOAT(8,2)
)
BEGIN
    IF _itm_id = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO items (itm_name, itm_price)
    VALUES (_itm_name, _itm_price);
ELSE
    UPDATE items
    SET
        itm_name = _itm_name,
        itm_price = _itm_price
    WHERE itm_id = _itm_id;
END IF;
END
```

Are the variables the problem? I've checked the table to see if I messed the names up, but it all seems fine to me.
Here's the table code

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
`itm_id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`itm_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`itm_price` FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`itm_id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `itm_name` (`itm_name`)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to redefine `Delimiter` to something else, for eg: `$$`. This allows parser to ignore `;` (hence do not execute statement on reaching `;`).
- Also, as a good practice, always use `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS`, to avoid failing out in case procedure with same name already exists.
- At the end, redefine the Delimiter back to `;`

Try the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `ItemsAddOrEdit` $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `ItemsAddOrEdit`(
_itm_id INT,
_itm_name VARCHAR(255),
_itm_price FLOAT(8,2)
)
BEGIN
    IF _itm_id = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO items (itm_name, itm_price)
    VALUES (_itm_name, _itm_price);
ELSE
    UPDATE items
    SET
        itm_name = _itm_name,
        itm_price = _itm_price
    WHERE itm_id = _itm_id;
END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Cheers mate! Works like a charm, never knew you had to manually make the parser read past ;

Comment: @JimmyNeutron happy to help :)