# syntax error trigger before update with if statement

Tags: mysql

I keep getting a syntax error from:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_updateOrderDate AFTER UPDATE ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.OrderStatus = 'ordered' THEN
        UPDATE Orders
        SET Orders.OrderDate = CURRENT_DATE()
        WHERE Orders.OrderId = NEW.OrderId;
    END IF;
END;
```

The error goes away if I remove the whole IF statement, but still returns an error if I replace the if statement with something basic like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_updateOrderDate AFTER UPDATE ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF 1=1 THEN

    END IF;
END;
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: You need to use a `DELIMITER` when MySQL programs uses `;` .. something like `DELIMITER $$; CREATE TRIGGER tr_updateOrderDate AFTER UPDATE ON Orders...`  Be sure to "reset" it with `DELIMITER ;` if you need to execute more in that session..

Comment: You need to redefine delimiter. Check this possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671764/2469308

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem! Although now I've got:

Comment: #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable) but at least the syntax is OK.